# Getting angle vector makes with the x-axis

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If we have the velocity of a particle moving on a path, $\frac{dy}{dx}=0.43$ then why can we say that the angle the velocity vector makes with the x axis is $\arctan(0.43)$? I don't understand why this is.

Comment: Hint : $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0.43$ represents slope of tangent line. For any straight line, we have $\text{slope} = \tan (\text{inclination angle})$

Comment: http://images.books24x7.com/bookimages/id_15615/figu134_4.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slope = dy/dx = tan (theta)=0.43 .